# Ruby on Rails 4 - Can't update data after adding one extra field to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I built a RoR application as followed:
(I am at application root while typing the commands )

1- CREATE TICKET TABLE

```
rails generate scaffold ticket name:string seat_id_seq:string address:text price_paid:decimal email_address:string
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

2 - The application works and I could add data to database via RoR web interface

3 - I added **phone** field to the **ticket** table

```
rails generate migration AddPhoneToTickets phone:string
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

4 - I updated following VIEW files to add **phone** field to the VIEW files

```
sudo nano app/views/tickets/_form.html.erb
sudo nano app/views/tickets/index.html.erb
```

5 - The application works, but I can't add **phone** to existing ticket records or a new record.

Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: You need to update your `TicketsController`'s `:create` action. Beyond this we can't possibly help because you've shown us *zero* code for your form or the controller action itself.

Comment: Thanks Deefour for your hint, I've posted an answer to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should show model for Ticket. And also make sure to read your server log.

But most probably your are failing in adding `phone` to `attr_accessible`:

```
attr_accessible ..., :phone
```

For Rails 4 see answer of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

So I followed **Deefour**'s comment and update the **app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb** file.
I only modified the **ticket_params** method to add the **phone** field, everything is working now.

BEFORE

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :seat_id_seq, :address, :price_paid, :email_address)
    end
```

AFTER

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :seat_id_seq, :address, :price_paid, :email_address, :phone)
    end
```

Comment: Yes, this is Rails 4. I've updated the question title, thank you juanpastas.